# Can I arrange for refunded gas to go to the recipient instead of the sender?

Tags: transactions, gas, protocol

I've sent some small test transactions around and noticed that, unless gas is precisely calculated, if you try to send everything in one address to another, the spare gas ends up in the sender's account but is then unspendable if the network gas price goes up. If this is a systemic occurrence, it seems to me that this will end up with dust amounts in many unusable addresses.

If I am emptying one address into another, it makes sense for the destination account to receive the refund for unused gas. Can I express this in `sendTransaction`?